# How can I place text over the search bar in App bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to place row of three elements inside app bar over the search bar. It is better to see what I would like to implement on screenshot. I am trying to use stack and positioned but get my content overlap. I think it is better to show the whole code, because without it, it could be harder to understand what is my problem. I also tried to use Column, but row of text over the search bar was behind search bar and not above it

Code:

```
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      title: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top:0,
              right: 430,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                 Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   child: Text('business', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),),
                 ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('devs ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('You', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 140.0, top: 10, right: 30),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/Logo.png',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0, top: 23, bottom: 13),
                  child: Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0, top: 23, bottom: 13),
                  child: Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0, top: 23, bottom: 13),
                  child: Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0, top: 23, bottom: 13),
                  child: Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0, top: 23, bottom: 13),
                  child: Text(
                    'Test',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 78.0, top: 15, bottom: 13),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 318,
                    height: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 15, left: 20),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                        isDense: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17, right: 15.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.logout_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Log out',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I have now:  [image: design example of what I have now]

Answer (score 0):

you're using the `Stack` incorrectly:

```
Stack(
        children: [    
          SearchBar(), 
          Row(...), 
        ],
      ),
```

In Stack, the last added Item will be at the top.